# Using subdomain value as $_GET variable

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, get, subdomain

Currently my site url is set up using `mod_rewrite` and $_GET variables to load different content. Like this: 
`mysite.com/subsite/var1/var2`

I'd like to change that format to look like this: 
`subsite.mysite.com/var1/var2`

Is there an easy way to do this, or do I need to completely redesign my site's backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code, This will work for you which you want.

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]).mysite.com\$ mysite.com/$1 [NC]
```

Comment: Would there be a way to do this without actually creating a subdomain for my site, more so a dynamic get variable that is _looks_ like a subdomain

Comment: I have told you this way. You don't need to create the subdomain. Just put this code in the .htaccess file and this will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?[^.]+\.mysite\.com.*$
RewriteRule (.*) subsite/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Actually you haven't moved your subsite you just want to rewrite.  R=301 and L flags aren't appropriate.